# add button row not working on next button

Tags: jquery

I have trouble when i try to add my add button, it's working, but the next button after that, couldn't make an action anymore.

Please help me to solve this problem..

**This is my HTML Code :**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#add_seq').click(function() {
    $('#tbl_seq').append('<tr><td style="text-align: center;">1</td><td style="text-align: center;"><select class="form-control" id="" name="pic_id" style="width: 100%;"><option></option><option>2</option><option>3</option><option>4</option></select></td><td style="text-align: center;"><a href="#" id="del_seq" style="margin: 10px; color: #000;"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></a><a href="#" data-id="add_seq" style="margin: 10px; color: #000;"><i class="fas fa-plus-square"></i></a></td></tr>');
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tbl_seq" class="table table-bordered table-hover table-condensed table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style="text-align: center;">SEQUENCE</th>
      <th style="text-align: center;">PIC</th>
      <th style="text-align: center;">ACTION</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="text-align: center;">1</td>
      <td style="text-align: center;">
        <select class="form-control" id="" name="pic_id" style="width: 100%;">
          <option></option>
          <option>2</option>
          <option>3</option>
          <option>4</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td style="text-align: center;">
        <a href="#" id="del_seq" style="margin: 10px; color: #000;"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></a>
        <a href="#" id="add_seq" style="margin: 10px; color: #000;"><i class="fas fa-plus-square"></i></a>
      </td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: First of you get duplication ID's and that is a big NO NO, use classes for that. Second then try something like `$(document).on("click",".add_seq",function() {})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@rezawisnuw, Insted of using ID use the class and when you add button dnamically your code

```
 $('#add_seq').click(function () {
```

will never work you must have to write

```
 $('body').on('click', '#add_seq', function() {
```

check the below solution

```js
                  $(document).ready(function() {
$('body').on('click', '.btnAdd', function() {
 
                        $('#tbl_seq').append('<tr><td style="text-align: center;">1</td><td style="text-align: center;"><select class="form-control" id="" name="pic_id" style="width: 100%;"><option></option><option>2</option><option>3</option><option>4</option></select></td><td style="text-align: center;"><a href="#" id="del_seq" style="margin: 10px; color: #000;"><i class="fa fa-trash btnDelete"></i></a><a href="#" data-id="add_seq" style="margin: 10px; color: #000;"><i class="fa fa-plus-square btnAdd"></i></a></td></tr>');
                      });
$('body').on('click', '.btnDelete', function() {
 $(this).closest("tr").remove();
                       
                      });
               

                });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<table id="tbl_seq" class="table table-bordered table-hover table-condensed table-striped">
                          <thead>
                            <tr>
                              <th style="text-align: center;">SEQUENCE</th>
                              <th style="text-align: center;">PIC</th>
                              <th style="text-align: center;">ACTION</th>
                            </tr>
                          </thead>
                          <tbody>
                            <tr>
                              <td style="text-align: center;">1</td>
                              <td style="text-align: center;">
                                <select class="form-control" id="" name="pic_id" style="width: 100%;">
                                    <option></option>
                                    <option>2</option>
                                    <option>3</option>
                                    <option>4</option>
                                </select>
                              </td>
                              <td style="text-align: center;">
                                <a href="#" id="del_seq" style="margin: 10px; color: #000;"><i class="fa fa-trash btnDelete"></i></a>
                                <a href="#" id="add_seq" style="margin: 10px; color: #000;"><i class="fa fa-plus-square btnAdd"></i></a>
                              </td>
                            </tr>

                          </tbody>
                            </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of things you had wrong.

**First of all** you should not have more than one element with the same `id`. So you should change `id` to `class`

**Secondly** in appended rows you did not add an element with `id="add_seq"` but you added element with `data-id="add_seq"` which is not the same ([`data-*` attributes](https://www.w3schools.com/Tags/att_global_data.asp)).

**Lastly** If you want jQuery `click` event to work on dynamically created elements you should bind it to document and not to an element. Because binding to an elements binds it only to those elements that are currently in DOM.

**Here is an working example**

```js
$(document).on('click', '.add_seq', function() {
  $('#tbl_seq').append('<tr><td style="text-align: center;">1</td><td style="text-align: center;"><select class="form-control" id="" name="pic_id" style="width: 100%;"><option></option><option>2</option><option>3</option><option>4</option></select></td><td style="text-align: center;"><a href="#" class="del_seq" style="margin: 10px; color: #000;"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></a><a href="#" class="add_seq" style="margin: 10px; color: #000;"><i class="fas fa-plus-square"></i></a></td></tr>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<table id="tbl_seq" class="table table-bordered table-hover table-condensed table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style="text-align: center;">SEQUENCE</th>
      <th style="text-align: center;">PIC</th>
      <th style="text-align: center;">ACTION</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="text-align: center;">1</td>
      <td style="text-align: center;">
        <select class="form-control" id="" name="pic_id" style="width: 100%;">
          <option></option>
          <option>2</option>
          <option>3</option>
          <option>4</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td style="text-align: center;"><a href="#" class="del_seq" style="margin: 10px; color: #000;"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></a><a href="#" class="add_seq" style="margin: 10px; color: #000;"><i class="fas fa-plus-square"></i></a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, i forget to change my id into class before i ask here, so thanks for remind me and like you said my jquery click event not doing well

Comment: @rezawisnuw If you used my answer then please accept if. If it helped you, you can also vote up.